# In GCP, how to change default pool name while creating through gcloud cli?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a GKE cluster with custom node-pool name. I am able to create from GUI but not find any option in gcloud to change default pool-name. Can any one help me to customize default pool name while creating GKE cluster through gcloud cli? Thanks

Comment: Just as a kind reminder take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers , if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To rename the *default node pool* at the creation of a GKE cluster is not possible neither when you have the cluster created.
With [gcloud container node-pools update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/update) you can modify the following parameters:

`gcloud container node-pools update NAME (--node-locations=ZONE,[ZONE,…]     | --system-config-from-file=SYSTEM_CONFIG_FROM_FILE     | --workload-metadata=WORKLOAD_METADATA     | --enable-autoprovisioning --enable-autoscaling --max-nodes=MAX_NODES --min-nodes=MIN_NODES     | --enable-autorepair --enable-autoupgrade     | --max-surge-upgrade=MAX_SURGE_UPGRADE --max-unavailable-upgrade=MAX_UNAVAILABLE_UPGRADE) [--cluster=CLUSTER] [--region=REGION     | --zone=ZONE, -z ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]`

But not the name.

**The workaround is:**

1. Create a new nodepool with the desired name.
   This is just an example I got from this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool#creating_a_node_pool_with_large_machine_type) it is to change the machine type but it also works to create a new nodepool with another name.

```
gcloud container node-pools create new-node-pool \
  --cluster=mycluster\
  --machine-type=e2-highmem-2 \
  --num-nodes=5
```

[Migrate the workloads](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool#step_4_migrate_the_workloads) :

- Cordon the existing node pool.
- Drain the existing node pool.

and then [Delete the old nodepool.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool#deleting_the_old_node_pool)